# In Go, is it convention to capitalize type names?

Tags: go

In most Go programs I have seen, even those that have just one package, the names of types are written with a capital letter, which makes them exported.

Is this just a convention to make clear that they are types or is there a need for all types to be exported?

Initially I was going to put examples here of exported types, but looking around some popular Go projects I *only* found exported types so far. So any example of an unexported type in a reasonably large Go project would be welcome.

Comment: There isn't a need for all types to be exported. It is not a convention. Upper vs low case on the names of identifiers in a package is chosen for functional reasons.

Comment: Some people write their main package types with Uppercase, and some don't. If the type doesn't need to be exported, then there is no other reason.

Comment: side point : as types starting with small case are private, go-doc is not able to generate documentation for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types can be private.

Having a public function returning a private type however does not work. As long as the type is only used package internally, I keep it private.

EDIT:
In your example, Server has to be public because it is returned by public functions and thus used outside the package. The function NewServer returns *Server.

EDIT for new example:

In the new example this is the main package. It can't be imported anyway.

Comment: Do you have examples of unexported types in a reasonably popular Go project?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question as I don't know any Go project that does not have internal types. Here is one example: https://github.com/hashicorp/raft/blob/main/commitment.go `commitment` is an internal type.

Comment: The idea is to expose as little as possible and necessary to the outside e.g. to keep things simple for the user of a Go module or Go package. There is also the `internal` folder used by many projects to hide entire packages even if they have exported types.

Answer (score 12):

The type starting with an uppercase letter are exported to other packages. Those starting with a lowercase letter can be used only inside the package. Important note: it is possible to export an interface without exporting the struct that implements it.

It is not a convention to export types. Only export them if you allow them to be used outside the package. In the example you provided, there was no need to export the `Server` type, because it has no exported field or methods.

Export only the types that are part of the contract with the client. Exporting types that are only used internally is a mistake and is confusing in the documentation.

Edit:

A little clarification about the `Server` type. It implements the `http.Handler` interface (must define `ServeHTTP(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` ), so it is possible to make it not exported and use the interface as the return type of `NewServer` function.

Comment: actually in the example Server has an exported function and it is also returned by the exported function NewServer. It has to be exported.

Comment: @TehSphinX The `Server` type implements `http.Handler`, so it is possible to hide it behind the `http.Handler` interface.

Comment: yes, you are right. But wouldn't NewServer have to return http.Handler then if we wanted to unexport the Server variable?

Comment: Do you have examples of unexported types in a reasonably popular Go project?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of convention, Go actually uses capitalization to determine which things are exported, i.e. available when you import the package.

E.g. if I have:

```
package a

const Exported = "hi"
const nonExported = "mom"
```

Then in a different package, you can import `a.Exported` but not `a.nonExported`:

```
package main

import "PATH/a"

func main() {
  println(a.Exported)
  // this won't compile
  // println(a.nonExported)
}
```

Comment: I know that it makes them exported, I actually wrote it in my question (now twice). I want to know why all those example export their types.